# codeigniter global variable need to be accessed by multiple controllers

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, global-variables

I am new to codeigniter , In my program i want a variable need to be accessed by multiple controllers, 
It's not a constant variable, value of variable changes ,

Sorry , My mistake 
I want to store a JSON object to be precise

Pls help me to figure this out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your website use session data? Maybe declaring globals could work?

Comment: yes i use session data ,
Sorry i want to store a JSON object to be precise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1

Since you are using CodeIgniter and sessions then something like this could work out for you:

**set it**

```
$someJSONobject = 'JSON';

$this->session->set_userdata('GLOBAL_JSON', $someJSONobject);
```

**retrieve it**

```
$someJSONobject = $this->session->userdata('GLOBAL_JSON');

echo $someJSONobject->subitem;
```

Make sure you are storing sessions in a DB if you go with this option because Cookie space is VERY limited

### Option 2

Even if you are not using CodeIgniters' session implementation then you can do something quite similar in native PHP:

```
$someJSONobject = 'JSON';

$_SESSION['GLOBAL_JSON'] = $someJSONobject;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base controller with an attribute for your variable, then have your controllers extend that base controller.

Answer (score 0):

Appending on Rooneyl's solution you may want to save that value on session which is easier to access from all end

[Session docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)